# pCloud API autentification procedure to upload/download files

Tags: python-3.x, oauth-2.0, python-requests, pcloud

I'm trying to automate an upload process to pCloud. I already have a pCloud "App" with `client ID` and `client Secret` with **All permissions (read, write, create, modify)** and **Allow implicit grant** allowed with `URI` to **http://localhost:65432/**. All my API calls use the European `eapi`.

I tried to authenticate myself with pCloud API with `username` + `password` with no success: I get a message saying I can't authenticate myself because I have a double authentication method set. I found no mention of a double authentication argument, so I guess the API does not support it (yet?).

I later tried using [tomgross's pcloud API](https://github.com/tomgross/pcloud). Authentication with email+password (specifying endpoint) does not succeed. I tried [OAuth 2.0](https://github.com/tomgross/pcloud#oauth-20-authentication) procedure with app client ID and secret, but it opens a pCloud page displaying **This 'redirect_uri' is not autorized.**...

I lastly tried using `requests` with the [pCloud API documentation](https://docs.pcloud.com/), but I do not manage to get a working `code` nor `token` to authenticate myself.

To summarize the full process, I would like to have a Python script run from github CI (headless) to upload files to a pCloud folder, and also have another Python function run by the client app that downloads the files from this pCloud folder. The folder should be only editable from the upload script to prevent the files from being changed by someone else.